# How to print Malayalam as c/c++ program output?

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, encoding

I am trying to print Malayalam (a south Indian Language) as c/c++ program output but it shows some unfamiliar characters both in terminal and in user interface using WINAPI.

*(The file "malayalam.txt" contain some Malayalam words.)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

main() {
    char s[100];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("malayalam.txt", "r");   
    if (fp == NULL) {
        puts("Cannot open file");
    }
    while (fgets(s, 100, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", s);
        MessageBox(NULL, s, "Malayalam", MB_OK);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Please use the appropriate tags, also there is no c/c++ it's c or c++. And the solution depends on that, you have to post your attempts so far too.

Comment: Show the code you're talking about. As it stands its difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale

Comment: what is printed all depends on the 'locale', the code page number, the 'font' that are currently being used.   Most likely, all the printing will need to be performed using a wide char formatting.   What is your code using for these print characteristics?   Also, does your print driver and printer support the needed graphics?

Comment: And the difference between using `std::cout <<` and `printf()` is fundamental, hence the language tag must be one of c or c++.

Answer (score 4):

The example from the following link may help you fix this issue for WINAPI.

You need to find the unicode equivalent of your Malayalam word in the `.txt` file you can convert it from here [http://www.aksharangal.com](http://Aksharangal%20Malyalam%20to%20unicode)

An example from the following page [http://harikrishnanvs.blogspot.in/2011/12/printing-malayalam-as-c-program-output.html](http://Example)

WIN32 program to print my name in Malayalam -MessageBox

This works for windows 7, but not working in XP
Create new project in visual studio 2010.
File-->New-->Project-->Win32 Project
Name the project
click OK
Finish

include header files `stdafx.h`, `tchar.h`.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCommandline,int iCmdshow)
{
    TCHAR c[4];
    c[0]=3385;
    c[1]=3376;
    c[2]=3391;
    c[3]='\0';
    TCHAR szbuffer[100];

    _stprintf(szbuffer,_T("%ls"),c);
    MessageBox(NULL,szbuffer,TEXT("HELLO ALL"),0);
    return 0;
}
```

Please ensure that , Configuration Properties--->Character set---> Use Unicode Character Set option is selected.

Comment: `TCHAR` should be `WCHAR` or `wchar_t` instead. `_stprintf` should be `_swprintf`. `MessageBox` should be `MessageBoxW`.